# Scala play framework: complex read to match multiple keys for same field in case class

Tags: scala, playframework

i'm a scala newbie...

let's say i have a case class like this:

```
case class Event(name: Option[String]) {}
```

i want to use the Play framework to parse it. however, sometimes i get a json payload where the first letter of the key is uppercase and sometimes lowercase. like so:

lowercase

```
{
  "name": "group_unsubscribe",
}
```

uppercase

```
{
  "Name": "group_unsubscribe",
}
```

how can i account for these possibilities using a complex reads?

i have tried with things like:

```
implicit val reads: Reads[Event] = (
((JsPath \ "name").readNullable[String] or
(JsPath \ "Name").readNullable[String])
)(Event.apply _)
```

but no joy :(

Answer (score 3):

You need to re-write your `Reads` as:

```
implicit val reads: Reads[Event] = (
  (JsPath \ "name").readNullable[String] orElse
  (JsPath \ "Name").readNullable[String]
).map(Event(_))
```

**Update 1** taking into account the comments:

```
import play.api.libs.json.Reads

implicit val reads: Reads[Event] = (
  (JsPath \ "name").read[String] orElse
  (JsPath \ "Name").read[String]
).map(name => Event(Option(name)))
```

Note: this implementation assumes that either "name" or "Name" will always be present in the incoming JSON document.

In order to capture the possibility of failure, you should use `.validate[T]` instead of `.as[T]`.

**Update 2** taking into account further comments:

Whether you have one or more attributes in your type doesn't change much. If your type had another field called `somethingElse` you would need to adapt your `Reads` to something like:

```
implicit val reads: Reads[Event] = (
  ((JsPath \ "name").read[String] orElse
  (JsPath \ "Name").read[String]).map(Option(_)) ~
  (JsPath \ "somethingElse").read[String]
)(Event.apply _)
```

Comment: is the map required? if so, is there a particular import that's required? i get `value map is not a member of play.api.libs.functional.FunctionalBuilder`

Comment: This compiles fine, but `Json.parse("""{"Name": "james"}""").as[Event]` returns `Event(None)` for me.

Comment: yes, sorry - i was trying with a more complex type and i didn't have access to map i assume cos i had multiple value types. i get the same as @JamesWhiteley. so, in reality i need to parse a type that has multiple json value types, i.e. string, int etc